# Is it possible to show multiple rows for a horizontal legend in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

Has anyone seen any overrides or extensions to allow for multiple rows for a horizontal legend in dc.js?  I currently need to have two lines of 3 items.

Comment: This should happen automatically. Have you set [legend.legendWidth()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.legend.html#legendWidth__anchor)?

Comment: @Gordon Correct! Just when I thought I was understanding the API's. While skimming the API I thought legendWith was for individual items.  Nope, that is what itemWidth does.  Thanks.